# This transaction cannot be completed... - paypal sandbox

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

am using paypal sandbox for test process in woocommerce - wordpress.

But it always shows "This transaction cannot be completed...".

i couldn't find why it shows like that. Please any one help me

Comment: Are you using your sandbox test user accounts from https://developer.paypal.com/

Comment: yes. am using developer.paypal.com

Comment: Do you have username,password and signature of paypal sandbox.

Comment: Yes. I have username,password and signature of paypal sandbox. please explain how to test in woocommerce. it shows transaction cannot be completed. why?

Comment: I have the same problem right now, is it an issue with paypal or something?